# How to use multiple functions, File-Out and del, in single Powershell command?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am using Powershell v4.0 to remove some duplicate files off of our drive and generate some reports. Our hope is no one will care that we're removing duplicate files - but if they do then I can just restore the files to their location.

I create a report showing all duplicates. I create a report of all the files I'll keep. I create a report of all the files I'll erase. And finally I actually make the deletion.

The first command is to get a report of all the duplicate files that I have:

```
ls *.*| Get-FileHash | group -Property hash | where { $_.count -gt 1 } | % { $_.group | select } | Out-File "c:\users\me\desktop\duplicatelist.txt"
```

The second command is to get a report of all the files I'll keep:

```
ls *.*| Get-FileHash | group -Property hash | where { $_.count -gt 1 } | % { $_.group[0] | select } | Out-File "c:\users\me\desktop\keep.txt"
```

The third command is to get a report of all the files I'll erase:

```
ls *.*| Get-FileHash | group -Property hash | where { $_.count -gt 1 } | % { $_.group | select -skip 1} | Out-File "c:\users\me\desktop\delete.txt"
```

The fourth command is to delete all of the duplicate files:

```
ls *.*| Get-FileHash | group -Property hash | where { $_.count -gt 1 } | % { $_.group | select -skip 1} | del
```

Can I combine multiple commands? It takes eight hours and thirty minutes per iteration of the command, so running it four times doesn't seem like a great solution.

In the least to be able to print out what I'm deleting, and to delete the files at the same step would be a good step forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than hashing 4 times, save the hashes to a variable to reuse:

```
$groupedhashes = ls *.*| Get-FileHash | group -Property hash | where { $_.count -gt 1 }

$groupedhashes | % { $_.group | select } | Out-File "c:\users\me\desktop\duplicatelist.txt"
$groupedhashes | % { $_.group[0] | select } | Out-File "c:\users\me\desktop\keep.txt"
$groupedhashes | % { $_.group | select -skip 1} | Out-File "c:\users\me\desktop\delete.txt"
$groupedhashes | % { $_.group | select -skip 1} | del
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @BenH I'd suggest only getting the files and hashing once, but there's no reason to loop through the whole thing 4 times. Just put all four commands in one `ForEach` loop.

```
ls *.*| Get-FileHash | group -Property hash | where { $_.count -gt 1 } | % {
    $_.group | Out-File "c:\users\me\desktop\duplicatelist.txt"
    $_.group[0] | Out-File "c:\users\me\desktop\keep.txt"
    $_.group | select -skip 1 | Out-File "c:\users\me\desktop\delete.txt"
    $_.group | select -skip 1 | del
}
```

**Edit:** Better yet, combine the last two commands with `Tee-Object` so it comes out to this:

```
ls *.*| Get-FileHash | group -Property hash | where { $_.count -gt 1 } | % {
    $_.group | Out-File "c:\users\me\desktop\duplicatelist.txt"
    $_.group[0] | Out-File "c:\users\me\desktop\keep.txt"
    $_.group | select -skip 1 | Tee-Object -FilePath "c:\users\me\desktop\delete.txt" -Append | del
}
```